# Failed dbunit test leaves transaction open

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, dbunit

I have set up dbunit (2.4.9) to work with my hibernate (4.2.19) code. All is working well until an exception is thrown during an insert. The test case fails (correctly) but the db transaction is left open and I have no way to close it.

Here is my base test case that extends from dbUnits DbTestCase. I am guessing that my tearDown method isn't getting called.

```
public class DbTestCase extends DBTestCase
{
 private static boolean doOnce = false;
 private Session session;

 public DbTestCase() throws Exception
 {
    super();
    //This connection info is duplicated in dbu.hib.cfg.xml
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:SID" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME, "schema" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD, "psswd" );

}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    if(!doOnce)
    {
        doOnce = true;

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        EbigHibernateFactory.setImplementation(new DbUnitHibUtils());
        EbigHibernateFactory.initilize();
    }

    session = EbigHibernateFactory.getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}

public void tearDown() throws Exception
{  
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    if(session.isOpen())
    {
        session.close();  
    }
    super.tearDown();  
}  

@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception
{
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream("src/dbtest/dataset.xml"));
}

}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your tearDown() and debug, you'll find out for certain whether it's getting called. Likely the exception from getDataSet() is halting the normal JUnit lifecycle.

Comment: Have you tried to catch exceptions in the tearDown method and use the the catch/finally block to close the transaction?